# which cf_sql type shall I use for MS-SQL SmallMoney type?

Tags: jdbc, coldfusion

The [doc](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f6f.html) didn't say, but shall I use `CF_SQL_MONEY` or `CF_SQL_MONEY4`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [CF8 docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_p-q_18.html) are better. They say use `CF_SQL_DECIMAL` for

- smallmoney
- money
- decimal

The [MS SQL driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378878%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) also uses `DECIMAL` for those data types.

**Update:**
CF9 also represents them differently. `DECIMAL` definitely seems the better choice for representing currency.

- CF_SQL_DECIMAL => `java.math.BigDecimal`
- CF_SQL_MONEY   => `java.lang.Double`  **** approximate type
- CF_SQL_MONEY4  =>  `java.lang.Double`  **** approximate type

Comment: so I guess `CF_SQL_DECIMAL` would be the safest bet, but `CF_SQL_MONEY` would work too.

Comment: It may not error, but `CF_SQL_MONEY` is the wrong type in this case (because it maps to java.lang.Double). *Approximate* numeric types should not be used for representing currency. I am sure that is why the MS docs recommend using `DECIMAL`.